# Bash: Dialog-command doesn't execute inside while loop

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop, dialog

If I run just `dialog --title "Titletext" --dselect /path/ 20 60` everything works fine. But when I put it in a while-loop the `echo` will be executed but not the `dialog --title "Titletext" --dselect /path/ 20 60` (see listing below).

```
repeat=true
while $repeat
do
  echo "test do"
  dialog --title "Titletext" --dselect /path/ 20 60
done
```

Comment: Those look like "smart quotes" and I wouldn't be surprised if that was some of the problem, try replacing them with regular quotes and see if that works better

Comment: I just saw that Error. But I have the right code in my original code. Wrong ones were only here.

Comment: The only problem I have with the posted code is if my window is too small to hold the requested dialog box. Otherwise, it works fine.